# Is there a way to share elements of overlapping maps?

Tags: java, enumeration

This a little something I stumbled upon while programming and I wonder whether anyone could provide me with some insights here.

Imagine you have some `enum`-like classes, i.e. classes with loads of instances defined as constants of the class. As an example consider something like

```
public class ChildName {

    private static final Map<String, ChildName> LUT = new TreeMap<>();

    private final String name;

    private ChildName(String name) {
        this.name = name.toLowerCase();
        LUT.put(name, this);
    }

    public static Collection<ChildName> getNames() {
       return LUT.values();
    }

    public static ChildName fromValue(String name) {
        return LUT.get(name);
    }

    public static final ChildName SARAH = new ChildName("Sarah");
    public static final ChildName MEGAN = new ChildName("Megan");
    public static final ChildName SANDY = new ChildName("Sandy");
    public static final ChildName JOHN = new ChildName("John");
    public static final ChildName BORIS = new ChildName("Boris");
    // etc...
}
```

Now, one could argue that it might be necessary to split up between boy's names and girl's names (or consider names from different countries or whatever, you get the idea). The idea would be that you can still list all of the possible names, but also all the names for boys or all the names for girls. This could be done with something like

```
public class ChildName {

    private static final Map<String, ChildName> LUT = new TreeMap<>();

    private final String name;

    protected ChildName(String name) {
        this.name = name.toLowerCase();
        LUT.put(name, this);
    }

    public static Collection<ChildName> getNames() {
        return LUT.values();
    }

    public static ChildName fromValue(String name) {
        return LUT.get(name);
    }

    // maybe here there are some gender-neutral names as constants left
    public static final ChildName ALEX = new ChildName("Alex");
}

public class GirlsName {

    private static final Map<String, ChildName> LUT = new TreeMap<>();

    private GirlsName(String name) {
        super(name);
        LUT.put(name, this);
    }

    public static Collection<ChildName> getNames() {
        return LUT.values();
    }

    public static final ChildName SARAH = new ChildName("Sarah");
    public static final ChildName MEGAN = new ChildName("Megan");
    public static final ChildName SANDY = new ChildName("Sandy");
    // etc...
}

public class BoysName {

    private static final Map<String, ChildName> LUT = new TreeMap<>();

    private BoysName(String name) {
        super(name);
        LUT.put(name, this);
    }

    public static Collection<ChildName> getNames() {
        return LUT.values();
    }

    public static final ChildName JOHN = new ChildName("John");
    public static final ChildName BORIS = new ChildName("Boris");
    // etc...
}
```

which could lead to huge `Map`s in each of the classes with massive overlaps.

There is probably not that much of a problem concerning efficiency or memory in this case, but despite that, it is still quite redundant and does not feel pretty.

It can be argued that the `Map` in the upper class could be omitted (assume the gender-neutral names are just duplicated in the subclasses or so) and the collection of all results could be retrieved from combining the collections of the subclasses. However, I would like to avoid this approach from a design point of view (imagine how messy that might get in case of a subclass for each country on this planet).

A more elegant solution (in my eyes) would be to keep a `Map` in every class, but in such a way that they share entries. Now I was wondering whether someone would now if this could be possible using a basic `Map` implementation. Other suggestions to solve this kind of problem are of course also welcome.

PS: I am aware that my proposal for an elegant solution is in fact not that much better, but I just can't come up with a better idea and I can't stop wondering how such kind of map could be implemented

Comment: Any reason you're not using an actual enum?

Comment: I guess the main reason is code duplication (some more functionality, override equals, hashcode, ...). I feel a bit stupid now...
Nevertheless I stay interested whether it is possible/useful to construct `Map`s that share entries

Comment: @shmosel I might not have been THAT stupid: I did not use enums, because I want to allow people to create their own names (so it suffices to list the common names)

Comment: Well that changes the whole question. How are you supposed to maintain a collection of instances if you're letting anyone construct one?

Comment: @shmosel You could look at it as a [Flyweight](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight) with a set of starting instances

Answer (score 0):

Go one step further than `enum`-like, and make them `enums`:

```
interface ChildName {}

enum GirlsName implements ChildName  {
    Sarah, Megan, Sandy
}

enum BoysName implements ChildName  {
    John, Boris
}
```

Now look up map is not needed:

```
ChildName name = BoysName.valueOf("Boris");
```

I'll let you write the code to find either boy's or girl's name.

Comment: in this case `name.valueOf()` is easy, but what if some cat lady decides to add an enum `PetName` or to make my point more clear: she adds`LovelyCatName`, `DirtyDogName`, `YummyGoldfishName`, etc...
At some point it gets pretty ugly and not that easy to maintain, not?

Comment: @MrTsjolder The OP has said that all names are (hard-coded) static constants

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an actual `enum`, and instead of grouping them into distinct classes, storing attributes such as country and gender on the `ChildName` class, then filtering and grouping as necessary.

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE
}

public enum Country {
    USA, CA, UK
}

public enum ChildName {
    SARAH(FEMALE, USA),
    MEGAN(FEMALE, CA),
    SANDY(FEMALE, UK),
    JOHN(MALE, USA),
    BORIS(MALE, UK);

    private static final Map<String, ChildName> LUT;
    static {
        LUT = Array.stream(values())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.name().toLowerCase()));
    }

    public static Collection<ChildName> getNames() {
       return Arrays.asList(values());
    }

    public static ChildName fromValue(String name) {
        return LUT.get(name.toLowerCase());
    }

    // some examples of filtering and grouping
    // if necessary, they can be cached statically (like LUT)
    public static List<String> getMaleNames() {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(c -> c.getGender() == MALE)
                .map(ChildName::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static Map<Gender, List<ChildName>> getGenderMapForCountry(Country country) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(c -> c.getCountry() == country)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ChildName::getGender));
    }


    private final Gender gender;
    private final Country country;

    ChildName(Gender gender, Country country) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
}
```